# Help me re-find an article about Galois theory

Tags: galois-theory

A couple of years ago I stumbled upon an online article which explained Galois theory in a way which is completely different from the approaches found in most maths texts (like Ian Stewart's book for example).

I believe that it was written for students of Physics.
I recall that it presented the theory in terms of using polynomials as rules that are combined, perhaps to give a group of simplifying rules.
There was some point made about how the polynomials have to be compatible, or how some polynomials may bring no more information than ones already used.

That's about as much as I can remember, sorry, other than the fact that it was not written in Latex (it was written in Word perhaps), and was a regular black and white document (not a good-looking colourful presentation).

Anybody else seen this article and can post a link?
Many thanks.

Comment: Could it possibly have been this? http://www.cc.kyoto-su.ac.jp/project/MISC/slide/seminar-s/2011/120112Takeuchi.pdf

Comment: Thanks but no. It does however look very nice. (I updated my question to state that it was definitely a black and white document).

Answer (score 0):

Could it been this particular article? http://www.math.chalmers.se/~dener/Galois-theory-of-Covers.pdf

Or maybe this one? http://math.illinoisstate.edu/schebol/teaching/407-14-files/Stewart-galois_theory.pdf

Comment: Nope, sorry :-(   But thanks for posting.

Comment: was it a pdf. file?

Comment: Yes I think so. I mean, you typically notice (and remember) when something opens as a Word document, it is a rare event. So yes, I am reasonably sure that it was a PDF document (generated by Word, probably).